# Angular 2 | 401 Unauthorized

Tags: angular, api, typescript

Good day, I'm building a simple app that only gets the API data with a token but I'm having unauthorized access error...

Can someone help me figure out why am I getting this error?

**401 Unauthorized**

[image: Error Message]

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    })
    export class AppComponent {

    data: any = {};

        constructor( private http: Http ) { }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.getVoicepicData();
            this.getData();
        }

        getData(){
            let headers = new Headers({
                'Token': "TOKEN HERE",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });

            return this.http.get('http://apiURL.com/api/voice/get-voice-pick-
            file/', { headers: headers })
                .map((res: Response) => return res.json())
        }

        getVoicepicData() {
            this.getData().subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.data = data
            })
        }

    }
```

How can I handle this error? Can someone help me figure this out? And do I set the token correctly?

**EDIT:** 
Missing `import { Headers } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: There can be numerous reasons for 401: Token can be expired, invalid, corrupted, empty, etc. So let's start simple. I suggest you to check if token gets to the server-side?

Comment: yes it did get to servicer-side, and  i use it  with jquery and its working fine. its just when i use angular2 it did not seems to work.

Comment: Try new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }) instead of just { headers: headers }

Comment: im getting requestoptions is not defined. sorry to ask this im only new to angular

Comment: Add them to import where you import Http

Comment: already added and im still getting same error

Comment: Hmmm .. I’ll get back to it tomorrow . Too late now , sorry. Good luck with finding the solution !

Comment: mode of `Authorization` is not set?

Comment: already solved it, i only import Header on http :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let headers = new Headers({
                'Authentication': "bearer <space><TOKEN HERE>",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
```